# Express.js: How to refresh on DB change in backend?

Tags: javascript, arrays, express

I decided to make a janky chat site type thing to get me started working with requests and such.

My approach was to create an express.js server that takes in requests when the '/messageReciever' is posted to.

```
app.post("/messageReciever", (req, res) => {
        logMessage(req.body.message);
});
```

The next step was to make a 'client' that could send information to this end point:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("XMLHttpRequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function makePostRequest(url, json)
{
        let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        http.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}

function sendMessage(url, message)
{
    makePostRequest(url, {message: message});
    logMessage(message);
}
```

Both of these are fine. The issue I'm running into is, **once I receive the post request I want to refresh the main page of my site (to show the messages)**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', data = retrieveMessages());
});
```

I've tried basically everything I've found online:

```
res.redirect('back');
res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
res.redirect(req.originalUrl)
```

I used `res.redirect('back')` previously in my code, and it works. The issue is that I'm trying to refresh someone's connection to a site based on someone else's connection; meaning I can't use the response information like I normally could.

I've tried looking for ways to refresh pages from outside functions but I can't find anything.

(*I realize that there are easier ways to make a chat site that don't include weirdly sending data back and forth between two server's*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package called [`socket.io`](https://npmjs.com/package/socket.io). Socket.io allows you to send requests to a client once the server has some data.

##### Example:

Server:

```js
// Define express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Create the server
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
// Define socket.io
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
// Define the port for the server to listen on
let port = 3000;

function logMessage(message, id) {
    ...
    io.emit('message_sent_' + id, { message }); // Emit that a message was sent to the clients
}
function recieveMessages(id) {
    // Get the messages somehow
}

app.post('/messageReciever', (req, res) => {
    // req.body.message is your message and req.cookies.id is the clients random ID
    logMessage(req.body.message, req.cookies.id);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('id', 'some-generated-id'); // Set a cookie for the unique ID to fetch user messages
    res.render('index', { data: retrieveMessages() });
});

// Get the server listening to incoming requests
server.listen(port, () => console.log('my app is online');
```

Client:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    ...
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('message_sent_' + 'some-id', function(data) {
        // Do something with the data
    });
</script>
</html>
```

References:

- https://socket.io/docs/v4/
- http://expressjs.com/
- https://marques-robinson-project.medium.com/chat-app-with-socket-io-and-express-using-node-js-2293b87f47c3

Comment: Wow, I'm going to try this out. If it works then this is really cool!